# Reverse a multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, copy, reverse

I am trying to reverse a multidimensional array where the amount of columns in each row are not the same.

Right now, I've managed to reverse the array in the example, but what if column size change in each row? lets say the array consist of {{1},{1,2,3}, {1,2}.......} is there a smarter way to do this without using if-statements for each row?

```
int[][] array3 = new int[3][4];
int[][] array4 = {{1,2,3},{7,8,6},{3,2,1,0}};

int counter = 2;
for(int row=0; row<array4.length; row++)
{
    if(row == 2)
        counter = 3;
    for(int col=0; col<array4[row].length; col++)
    {
        array3[row][counter] = array4[row][col];
        counter--;
    }
    counter = 2;
}
```

Comment: Why not just set `counter` to `array4[row].length` ?

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but you could use `Collections.reverse()` with lists.

Comment: Thats actually not the issue here, but sure thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Please mention input and output. Your code doesn't seem reversing data correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two simple `for` loops iterating over the arrays and creating a new one:

```
int[][] reversed = new int[array.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int[] row = array[array.length - i - 1];
    reversed[i] = new int[row.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        reversed[i][j] = row[row.length - j - 1];
    }
}
```

With Java Streams you can use this, which does the same:

```
int[][] reversed = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> array[array.length - i])
        .map(row -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, row.length)
                .map(i -> row[row.length - i])
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

For the input array you showed:

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 6}, {3, 2, 1, 0}};
```

The result with both solutions will be this:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 7], [3, 2, 1]]
```